# How to display text coming from a dynamic List in JLabel

Tags: java, swing, for-loop, jlabel

in console we can do that like this :

```
 for(int i = 0 ; i <list.size();i++){
    System.out.print("name :"+list.get(i).getName());
    System.out.print("  year :"+list.get(i).getYear());
    System.out.println();
 }
```

if we know the size we can creat many label and do that

> label.setText("");

what is the best way to do that in swing if we don't know the size of our list ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
System.out.print("name :"+list.get(i).getName());
System.out.print("  year :"+list.get(i).getYear());
System.out.println();
```

For tabular information, use a [`JTable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html).  See [How to Use Tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) for more details and code.

[image: Swing Table]

---

Another tips: for command line output, look to [Formatting Numeric Print Output](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/numberformat.html).

Comment: I answered the OP's question, you answered the OP's need. +1

Comment: Glad you got a strategy to proceed with.  :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [HTML to format text](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/html.html) in any Swing component that displays text.

```
StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder("<html>");
for(String s : list) {
    b.append(s);
    b.append("<br>");
}

label.setText(b.toString()); // multiline JLabel
```

Comment: For a list I'd use an `ol` or `ul` & `li` elements, but this seems more like a `table`.

Comment: *"..more like a `table`."*  Or `JTable`!

Comment: @AndrewThompson is right, the best way to go would be to create a native table-like component in Java that would enable easy access to each individual cell. The easier but not as elegant way is to place an html 'table' in the label (I edited this answer to include this option, it should come up sooner or later when it gets accepted)

Comment: @Tom I would never want to see an HTML table in a `JLabel` when it would be much easier to just create a `JTable`. I wouldn't even want to suggest to someone to use an HTML table.

Comment: @Jeffrey  let's just agree it's as awful as a number of lines containing strings like (Year: 1999) with line breaks. JTable is certainly the way to go

Answer (score 0):

label.setText(label.getText() + " " + s);Use [`For-Each`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html) Loop.

for example:

```
for (String s : listOfStringType){
    label.setText(label.getText() + " " + s);
}
```

Comment: That will only display the text from the last entry in the list.

Comment: Then use label.setText(label.getText() + " " + s);